# SQL SCORE RANKING

Tags: mysql

I'm working with score ranking on my app for all user score. My problem is I don't know how to return one row for each stud_num.

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM score WHERE assess_type = 'professional' ORDER BY total_score DESC.
```

Result:
[image: RESULT]

As you can see I have 3 stud_num and I only want one row per stud_num and the highest score of it.

Comment: As you still didn't select an answer, I added the correct answer, try it out

Answer (score 2):

You can use correlated query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM score t
WHERE t.assess_type = 'professional' 
      AND t.total_score = (select max(s.total_score) 
                           from score s
                           where t.stud_num = s.stud_num)
group by stud_num
```

Comment: but note that an uncorellated subquery will be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Not sure I'm following , I can see how to do this with a join, but how with an uncorrelated subquery? @Strawberry

Comment: @MajikeroGallardo , did you try this answer?

Comment: this returns duplicates for stud_num 2 as it has 3 max values of 6, added the group by to remove the duplicates

Comment: @davejal that might work (and it might even be faster), but it's the wrong way to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Use the MAX and GROUP BY functions like this:

```
SELECT score_id, stud_num, assess_type, total_item, MAX(total_score), average, date_taken
FROM score 
WHERE assess_type = 'professional' 
GROUP BY stud_num 
ORDER BY 5 DESC
```

Comment: My bad. I just updated the post. The original one is not right. No data for trying, just write in mind. Thanks for the comment. @sagi

Comment: Its still not good, he want one row for each, so in your solution you either choose only half of the colums, or your idea won't work(score_id is different so each row will come as an output)

Comment: You are correct. I was trying to avoid the subquery. But missed something at the same time.

Comment: Except the stud_num, and MAX(total_score), all other columns may not from the MAX row, but from a different row in the same group. Anyway, if the correct stud_num and MAX(total_score) is acceptable already, with other columns maybe not from MAX row, but from the same group, this is still a solution, with NO subquery and join. @Majikero Gallardo can take a look.

Comment: Ty to ur idea I got the answer

Comment: @DylanSu So, you mean it's an answer to a different question from the one that was asked?

Comment: @Strawberry No. That depends on author's real requirement, which is not clearly presented in the post. Actually, the author got his expected result based on my answer. He add an answer post for that.

Comment: @dylansu I fear the author may be mistaken

Comment: @Strawberry Maybe. The undetermined result seems not so cool. what is your advice for this question? For the subquery solution, need to figure out a way to remove duplicate entries on max rows.

Comment: See comments to davejal's answer

Answer (score 0):

The option given by @sagi is good:

```
SELECT * FROM score t
WHERE t.assess_type = 'professional' 
      AND t.total_score = (select max(s.total_score) 
                           from score s
                           where t.stud_num = s.stud_num)
group by stud_num
```

---

Another option would be to use an inner join and group by together.

The resulting query would become:

```
select * from score a

inner join (
SELECT stud_num, max(total_score) tscore FROM `score` group by stud_num) b
on a.stud_num = b.stud_num and total_score= tscore

group by a.stud_num
```

try it out at [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56630/2/0)

Comment: If @Strawberry says it's not finished I'm all ears why or what I'm missing, is it the formatting (selecting all fields)?

Comment: @Strawberry please elaborate which part, I would like to learn

Comment: See the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score -1):

Here's my the ans:
SELECT score_id, stud_num, assess_type, total_item, MAX( total_score ) 
FROM score
WHERE assess_type =  'professional'
GROUP BY stud_num, total_item
ORDER BY MAX( total_score ) DESC

Comment: Is this from my answer?

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns indeterminate results for non-aggregated columns not in the GROUP BY